# Dutch National Flag Problem Running in O(n)

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dutch-national-flag-problem

I am a 10th-grade student in CompSci 1.  In our textbook, [Practical Programming 3rd Edition, An Introduction to Computer Science Using Python 3.6](https://pragprog.com/book/gwpy3/practical-programming-third-edition), it mentions the Dutch National Flag Problem.  The following is how it states the exercise, word for word:

> Edsgar Dijkstra is known for his work on programming languages.  He came up with a neat problem that he called the Dutch National Flag problem: given a list of strings, each of which is either "red", "green", or "blue" (each is represented several times in the list), rearrange the list so that the strings are in the order of the Dutch national flag--all the "red" strings first, then all the "green" strings, then all the "blue" strings.

Here is the python code that I wrote for the exercise:

```
def dutch_flag(colors: list)-> list:
  """
  This function takes a list of strings of colors (red, green, 
  or blue),and returns a list containing them with the reds first, 
  the greens second, and the blues last.
  """
  reds = 0
  greens = 0
  blues = 0
  for color in colors:
    color = color.lower().strip()
    if color == "red":
      reds += 1
    elif color == "green":
      greens += 1
    elif color == "blue":
      blues += 1

  flag = []
  for i in range(0, reds):
    flag.append("red")
  for i in range(0, greens):
    flag.append("green")
  for i in range(0, blues):
    flag.append("blue")

  return flag
```

My code runs in O(n) time.  However, my teacher told us that this program required a sorting algorithm, which is, at best, O(n*logn).  Why is my code faster?

Comment: Your code is correct and runs in O(2n) time because it does not sort anything. It would be interesting to see your teacher's version of this honestly. I think their version would work and **keep the order** with a more complex list like ["red ferrari", "green apple", "red cherry", "blue berries"].

Comment: Because you "cheated" and used prior knowledge about the problem. Which is completely valid option often. It depends on the requirement of rearranging the given array/list, or if you can return a different one.

Comment: By the way, if you want to get rid of the `range` and `append` you can do directly `flag = ["red"]*reds + ["green"]*greens + ["blue"]*blues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show is a counting sort. Other non-comparison options would be bucket or radix sort that also have O(n) time complexity.

It's also possible to solve this problem with a comparison based 3-way partition function that uses compares and swaps with time complexity O(n).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem#Pseudocode

Normally comparison based sorts take O(n log(n)) time, but the Dutch national flag problem doesn't require this.

The 3 way partition function can be expanded to handle a larger number of colors. The first pass separates the array into 3 sub-arrays, small, middle, large, then repeats the process on each sub-array to split it into 3 sub-sub arrays and so on.  9 colors could be done in 2 passes, 1st pass separates into small, middle, large, then 2nd pass separates each sub-array into 3 parts, which is also O(n) time complexity. For n elements and k colors, the time complexity is O(n⌈log3(k)⌉), but since k is a constant, the time complexity is O(n).